# What is the minimum output frequency according to this datasheet?

Tags: digital-logic, signal-processing

Can [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9850.pdf) DDS output down to 0.05Hz sine?

I think the resolution is 0.0291 Hz. Does that mean that is also the miimum freq. it can synthesize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at a clock frequency of 125 MHz.

You can always run it at a lower reference clock frequency — the minimum is 1 MHz, and a setting of 215 would give you an output frequency of 0.05006 Hz.

Comment: Thanks, I want to use this for a sine between 0.05Hz and 200Hz. I tried ICL8038 was not very easy to work with because of distortion ect. Im planning to use this https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07GVCWD2G/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2GCNYVN3N36YF&psc=1 but I might need a filter for such low freq.

Comment: And what is 215?

Comment: The frequency setting value: \$\frac{1\text{ MHz}}{2^{32}}\cdot 215 = 0.050058588\text{ Hz}\$

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the DDS is equal to the clock frequency divided by 2^32 since the tuning word is 32 bits long.  For a 125 MHz clock (the maximum allowed) this results in a minimum frequency of 0.029 Hz. If you need lower frequencies, just use a lower speed clock.  The minimum clock frequency specified is 1 MHz.  This would result in a minimum frequency of 0.0002328 Hz which could be increased in steps of the same amount. You could, of course, use any clock frequency between 1 and 125 MHz to suit your requirements.

Comment: I dont have any experience with DDS but  I want to use this for a sine between 0.05Hz and 200Hz. I tried ICL8038 was not very easy to work with because of distortion ect. Im planning to use this https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07GVCWD2G/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2GCNYVN3N36YF&psc=1 but I might need a filter for such low freq.

Comment: Im complete zero at the moment on the subject DDS. But can you just tell me what is the input to this DDS chip? I mean what kind of input controls the output sine frequency? I want to use a microcontroller like Arduino to vary the freq. vy using this module. But I couldn't figure out any examples.